# Java DateTimeFormatter with Optional Sections

Tags: java, java-time, datetimeformatter

I have done some reading on this and tried to work through examples from other StackOverflow threads but I keep running into an exception when parsing the date/time if I try to specify optional sections.

this is the input.  The optional sections are the AM/PM which may not always be in the input,  and the timezone which may be 4 characters:

```
09:10:05.584 AM EST Wed Nov 29 2023
```

This is the pattern that works for this input, but not other inputs, such as if there is no timezone

```
hh:mm:ss.SSS a zzz E MMM dd yyyy
```

If I try to do something like this and create optional patterns I get a parse exception at position 12 in the input, which is just after the milliseconds

```
hh:mm:ss.SSS[ a [z]zzz ]E MMM dd yyyy
```

this is the code, currently set to the format that fails:

```
public static final String TIME_FORMAT = "hh:mm:ss.SSS[ a [z]zzz ]E MMM dd yyyy";


public static String ParseDate(String input, String format) {
        
        
        String retVal = "";
        
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format, Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        TemporalAccessor ta = formatter.parseBest(input, LocalDateTime::from, LocalDate::from);
        
        retVal = ta.toString();
       
        System.out.println("Parsed date is: "+ retVal);
        return retVal;
    }
```

Comment: Ideally, you would educate the publisher of your data about using only standard formats defined in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) when communicating date-time values textually.

Comment: Pseudo time zones such as `EST` should *never* be used in data storage or data exchange. They are not standardized, and are not even unique! Use only [real time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in format of `Continent/Region`.

Comment: @BasilBourque I don't have a choice. I am collecting data  from some network equipment and the format that the system clock is shown is user specified.  One of the options is to have the timezone displayed.    I have no way of enforcing how the user formats the system clock display.  I want the system clock so that I can record the system time of the equipment when I do the data collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one, because the syntax for an optional section of the `DateTimeFormatter` class specifically wants the space between the optional element and its predecessor included within square brackets.

The documentation of the [parseBest()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseBest(java.lang.CharSequence,java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery...)) method shows an example of a pattern with an optional timezone ID, `uuuu-MM-dd HH.mm[ VV]`, where the space between the minute and the timezone ID is included within the optional section.

In your snippet, the first optional was written properly `hh:mm:ss.SSS[ a...` (with the space between `SSS` and `a` included within square brackets), but then the optional part for the timezone name was written `a [z]zzz` instead of `a[ z]zzz`. In your case, you can either nest the optional sections like so `hh:mm:ss.SSS[[ a] zzz] E MMM dd yyyy`, or write them as individual optional sections `hh:mm:ss.SSS[ a][ z][ zzz] E MMM dd yyyy`.

Here is a re-written version of your code covering the 4 cases:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        parseDate("09:10:05.584 AM EST Wed Nov 29 2023", TIME_FORMAT);
        parseDate("09:10:05.584 AM Wed Nov 29 2023", TIME_FORMAT);
        parseDate("09:10:05.584 EST Wed Nov 29 2023", TIME_FORMAT);
        parseDate("09:10:05.584 Wed Nov 29 2023", TIME_FORMAT);
    }
    public static final String TIME_FORMAT = "HH:mm:ss.SSS[ a][ z][zzz] E MMM dd yyyy";

    public static String parseDate(String input, String format) {
        String retVal = "";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format, Locale.ENGLISH);
        TemporalAccessor ta = formatter.parseBest(input, LocalDateTime::from, LocalDate::from);
        retVal = ta.toString();
        System.out.println("Parsed date is: " + retVal);
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

You can quickly check the code here at this link:

https://ideone.com/bpfw8o

Comment: Thanks.  I also noted your link is getting the same results I was where if the AM/PM is omitted the time is not parsed, only the date.  I changed the hh: to kk: and now get the time parsed whether or not the AM/PM is included in the input.

Comment: @DavidGreen you're right, I've just noticed. However, kk would be the right symbol only if the time is specified with hours between 1 and 24! If the hour is specified as a number within 0 and 23 you should use HH.  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns

Comment: thanks and noted.  I am parsing time from some networking equipment and will confirm whether it is 0-23 or 1-24.

Answer (score 0):

specifying the format this way:

```
public static final String TIME_FORMAT = "hh:mm:ss.SSS[ a][ z][ zzz] E MMM dd yyyy";
```

worked.  Trying to nest the [] was not working.

Comment: you can nest optional sections by properly including the space between elements within square brackets